# How to get the property name for a specific ID?

Tags: api, wikidata

Wikidata entities have claims, inside which are property IDs with their snaks. But how do I get the name for a particular property ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I admit it might have been a little bit obvious, maybe. You just use

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=<property-id>&languages=<lang>&props=labels&format=json
```

I know, the action is `wbgetentities`, but it does work! You get a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "entities": {
        "P463": {
            "type": "property",
            "datatype": "wikibase-item",
            "id": "P463",
            "labels": {
                "en": {
                    "language": "en",
                    "value": "member of"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "success": 1
}
```

This works because, oddly enough, properties themselves are entities in Wikidata.